# How to get class method definitions using clang python bindings?

Tags: python, c++, parsing, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

Given the following C++ file:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo();

  void bar(int input);

  void another(int input, double & output);
};

void
Foo::bar(int input)
{
  input += 1;
}

void
Foo::another(int input, double & output)
{
  input += 1;
  output = input * 1.2345;
}
```

How can I utilize clang python bindings to extract the definitions of the two methods. I am able to get the class declarations using the python script below, but I can't seem the figure out how to extract the complete methods. For example, I want this information:

```
void
Foo::another(int input, double & output)
{
  input += 1;
  output = input * 1.2345;
}
```

Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import clang.cindex
clang.cindex.Config.set_library_path('/opt/moose/llvm-3.7.0/lib')

def getCursors(cursor, output, kind):
    """
    Recursively extract all the cursors of the given kind.
    """
    for c in cursor.get_children():
        if c.kind == kind:
            output.append(c)
        getCursors(c, output, kind)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Parse the test file
    index = clang.cindex.Index.create()
    tu = index.parse('method.C', ['-x', 'c++'])

    # Extract the parsers
    output = []
    getCursors(tu.cursor, output, clang.cindex.CursorKind.CXX_METHOD)

    # Print the method declarations (How to I get the definitions?)
    for c in output:
        defn = c.get_definition() # Gives nothing
        print defn 
        print c.extent.start.file, c.extent.start.line, c.extent.end.line # Gives decleration
```

## FOLLOW UP:

The following function was suggested as a solution, but it doesn't work for clang 3.7. I am unable to update to 3.9 until it is released and I need to support the latest two versions of clang (3.7 and 3.8). If you add a print statement the results indicate that a definition is not located.

```
def method_definitions(cursor):
    for i in cursor.walk_preorder():
        print i.kind, i.is_definition() # Added this
        if i.kind != CursorKind.CXX_METHOD:
            continue
        if not i.is_definition():
            continue
        yield i
```

Running the method yields the following, anyone know what has changed between clang 3.7 and 3.9?

```
CursorKind.TRANSLATION_UNIT False
CursorKind.CLASS_DECL True
CursorKind.CXX_ACCESS_SPEC_DECL True
CursorKind.CONSTRUCTOR False
CursorKind.CXX_METHOD False
CursorKind.PARM_DECL True
CursorKind.CXX_METHOD False
CursorKind.PARM_DECL True
CursorKind.PARM_DECL True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close - the trick is to use the cursor offsets rather than line / columns, and that AFAIK, libclang doesn't expose the bytes of the source, so you need to read the text out yourself.

The following is tested on:

- Clang provided by Xcode 7.3(7D175) - OSX Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29) and pip installed bindings from pypi (`pip install 'clang==3.7'`)
- Ubuntu clang version 3.7.1-svn253742-1~exp1 (branches/release_37) (based on LLVM 3.7.1)
- Ubuntu clang version 3.6.2-svn240577-1~exp1 (branches/release_36) (based on LLVM 3.6.2)
- clang version 3.9.0-svn267343-1~exp1 (trunk)

The only caveats are that for more complex cases with macros / headers YMMV.

```
import clang.cindex
from clang.cindex import *

def method_definitions(cursor):
    for i in cursor.walk_preorder():
        if i.kind != CursorKind.CXX_METHOD:
            continue
        if not i.is_definition():
            continue
        yield i

def extract_definition(cursor):
    filename = cursor.location.file.name
    with open(filename, 'r') as fh:
        contents = fh.read()
    return contents[cursor.extent.start.offset: cursor.extent.end.offset]

idx = Index.create()
tu = idx.parse('method.C', ['-x', 'c++'])
defns = method_definitions(tu.cursor)
for defn in defns:
    print extract_definition(defn)
```

Which gives:

```
void
Foo::bar(int input)
{
      input += 1;
}
void
Foo::another(int input, double & output)
{
      input += 1;
        output = input * 1.2345;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, unfortunately this doesn't seem to work on 3.7. I can probably get updated to 3.8, but won't be able to use 3.9 until it is released (http://llvm.org/) since I am working on project that gets deployed.

Comment: I added a follow up question using your `method_definitions` method, the `is_definition()` method is never `True` on 3.7.

Comment: It appears that the problem you're describing doesn't appear in the (linux) releases available from apt repositories on llvm.org. I have a few other ideas - but they would only work if get_definition() return something other than `None` when the cursor kind is `CXX_METHOD`?

Comment: I am using OSX, but with a custom build of clang, so perhaps my build is not correct for using the python-bindings. I will try this out using system clang on OSX and on linux, but probably not until early next week. Thanks for the extra information and I will keep you posted.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this statement: "OSX and with the python bindings". What version of OSX and XCode (or Command Line Tools) are you using? Where did you get the python bindings from?

Comment: I've updated the question with the requested information

Comment: I finally got everything working on OSX, I apparently had some incompatibilities between my clang library and the python bindings. I fixed it by re-building clang.